# How to pass v:register to custom operator when working on custom text object?

Tags: custom-text-object, map-operator

I have a simple custom operator, it echoes `v:register`, it's mapped to `,f`. After reading [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12555/how-to-allow-count-before-my-custom-operator), i creat it like this :

```
function! s:foo(type,...)
  echo v:register
endfunction

function! s:setupOpfunc(func)
  let &opfunc = a:func
  return 'g@'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> ,f <sid>setupOpfunc('<sid>foo')
```

It wors fine on built in textobjects, e.g. `"x,faw` output

```
x
```

But it doesn't work on custom textobject. Assume i have this simple custom  text object:

```
vnoremap ix iw

" I know you can map to `iw` directly, but that's not the point of this problem.
onoremap ix :normal vix<cr>
```

`"x,fix` output

```
"
```

I think it doesn't work because `:normal ...` erased `v:resiter`. I tried to use `onoremap <expr> ...` to create `omap` for textobject, but [:h map-expression](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) says `:normal`( needed to visually select text object ) is blocked during it's expression evaluation.

Built in operator has no this kind of problem `"xyix` happily copy word into register `x`.

One crude way i know to make this work is to use some global variable:

```
function! s:setupOpfunc(func)
  let g:__opfunc_rgister = v:register
  ...
endfunction
```

But it doesn't feel right, are there any other ways to make this work?

Comment: One option is to make the text objects take care of this. For instance, `:onoremap ix :execute '"' . v:register . "normal vix"<cr>` will preserve the registers. However, I looked up a popular text objects package ([wellle/targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)) and noticed it doesn't preserve `v:register` across invocations, so I don't think that's the answer... This is a great question, also curious to figure out what the right answer to it is!

Comment: @filbranden very few plugin do it the "right way" so that's not a great benchmark.  Not to mention this could be a vim bug

Comment: @filbranden Your solution does output the right rigister, but `"` is start of comment in command line, so `"xnormal vix` is no different form `"xbalabalabala`, it's ignored,  `\`]` won't be set to the right value in `opfunc`.

Comment: @dedowsdi Great catch! I noticed sometimes I wasn't seeing a motion, didn't realize that was working as a comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider if you were doing some operation in visual mode for deleting in a word, you would use the following to put the deletion in register a.

```
viw"ad      ->   v        [iw]      ["a]       d
                 visual   object    register   operator
```

Similarly, placing `"a` in the omap after the operator `ix` passes it to the opfunc.  Either of these alternatives seems to work:

```
onoremap ix :normal vix"<c-r>=v:register<cr><cr>

onoremap <expr> ix ':normal vix"'.v:register.'<cr>'
```

At the point of creation of the normal string, `v:register` is set correctly.

I think this is a general principle.  If you make an omap that uses visual mode, you should save and append the register invocation for the sake of any following opfuncs

```
func! MyOmap()
    let l:reg = v:register
    normal! vaw
    execute 'normal! "' . l:reg 
endfunc
```

All that being said, custom text objects do work built-in operators without this extra work, so maybe vim should be fixed do the right thing here, with custom op + custom object.

Comment: Nice solution! It never comes to me that one can add extra stuff after `normal v**` in the `omap`. I always thought `"*` must appears before `g@`.